# How to check if stdin is still opened without blocking?

Tags: c, stream, stdin, nonblocking

I need my program written in pure C to stop execution when stdin is closed.

There is indefinite work done in program main cycle, and there is no way I can use blocking checks (like `getc()`) there (no data is supposed to arrive on stdin - it just stays opened for unknown time).

I intend to use described functionality in realization of network daemon hosted in inetd, xinetd or their analogs - it should emit data on stdout while connection stays opened and correctly finish work when it closes. Now my program is killed by hosting service as it won't stop after connection termination.

I wonder if `fctntl()` with `O_NONBLOCK` flag applied to stdin descriptor would allow me to use `read()` function in non-blocking mode? Should I use `select()` somehow?

P.S. The data is not supposed but might arrive to stdin. A way of non-blocking readout woould be an answer for the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**select()** does exactly what you want: signal that an operation (read, in this case) on a file descriptor (file, socket, whatever) will not block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int is_ready(int fd) {
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int ret;
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 1;
    //int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds,
     struct timeval *timeout);
    return select(fd+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You can now check a file descriptor before use, for instance in order to empty the file descriptor:

```
void empty_fd(int fd) {
    char buffer[1024];
    while (is_ready(fd)) {
        read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

In your case, use **fileno(stdin)** to get the file descriptor of stdin:

```
if (is_ready(fileno(stdin))) {
    /* read stuff from stdin will not block */
}
```

Comment: `poll` is also exactly what OP wants, and its interface is a bit easier than `select` when dealing with a small, fixed set of file descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if fctntl() with O_NONBLOCK flag applied to stdin descriptor would allow me to use read() function in non-blocking mode?

Running stdin with O_NONBLOCK has advantages over select.  Select says that there is some data, but not how much.  There are times that you want to get all available data, but not block, regardless of how much in in the queue.  Running select for each character seems like a lot of busy work... O_NONBLOCK did not work for me.  It is an internal flag, not exposed in most tty drivers.

Check out ioctl(..., FIONBIO). It seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you can set O_NONBLOCK on stdin, but `select()` or `poll()` will definitely get the job done.

Comment: Yes, you can set O_NONBLOCK on stdin.  If your stdin is piped from another program, though, that program may not handle its outbound file descriptor becoming non-blocking very well.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `feof(stdin)` ?

Comment: That won't work if you don't read out all data. How do I read out all data (trash for example) without blocking operations?

Comment: EOF can be injected into an open stdin (e.g. via Ctrl-D on Linux). It doesn't mean that stdin is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `select` (with a zero timeout).  You don't need to set the file descriptor non-blocking, though - if `select` tells you that the file descriptor is readable, then a `read` on it will definitely not block.

So, poll file descriptor 0 occaisionally with `select`, and if it's readable, `read` it.  If `read` returns 0, then that means it's been closed.