# How do I check if my program has data piped into it

Tags: c++, c, pipe, stdin

Im writing a program that should read input via stdin, so I have the following contruct.

```
FILE *fp=stdin;
```

But this just hangs if the user hasn't piped anything into the program, how can I check if the user is actually piping data into my program like

```
gunzip -c file.gz |./a.out #should work
./a.out  #should exit program with nice msg.
```

thanks

Comment: For the record, the program is not hanging; it's simply waiting for input. If you send an EOF (Ctrl-D on most platforms), it's interpreted as if the input ended early.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're using file pointers, you'll need both `isatty()` and `fileno()` to do this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = stdin;

    if(isatty(fileno(fp)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "A nice msg.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* carry on... */
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, that's the long way.  The short way is to not use file pointers:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "A nice msg.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* carry on... */
    return 0;
}
```

Several standard Unix programs do this check to modify their behavior.  For example, if you have `ls` set up to give you pretty colors, it will turn the colors off if you pipe its stdout to another program.

Answer (score 3):

Passing stdin to select() or poll() should tell you if input is waiting.  Under many OSes you can also tell if stdin is a tty or pipe.

EDIT: I see I'm going to have to emphasize the *also* part of the tty test.  A fifo is not a tty, yet there might be no input ready for an indefinite amount of time.

Comment: I think the OP just wanted to cover the run-on-command-line-and-wonder-why-it-"hangs" case.  Probably trying to fix a PEBKAC bug.  Sitting there waiting on a FIFO or other pipe would be okay.

Answer (score 3):

Try "man isatty", I think that function will tell you if you are talking to the user or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `isatty` to detect that stdin is coming from a terminal rather than a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

See the function "isatty" - if STDIN is a terminal, you can skip reading from it. If it's not a terminal, you're getting data piped or redirected and you can read until EOF.

Answer (score 0):

An additional option you get with select() is setting a timeout for reading from stdin (with respect to either the first read from stdin or consecutive reads from stdin).

For a code example using select on stdin see:

[How to check if stdin is still opened without blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594251/how-to-check-if-stdin-is-still-opened-without-blocking)