# isatty() is always returning 1 from eshell (emacs)

Tags: c++, stdin, gnu

Why isatty never identifies that my program is using redirected stdin when using emacs? This is my code:

```
int val = isatty(STDIN_FILENO);
std::cout << val << std::endl;
```

If I launch my program from eshell (emacs): `./a.out` it will return 1, and if I launch `ls | ./a.out` it will also return 1.

Why does it happen? Which conditions trigger this? Launching this from python (using POPEN(shell=True)) is safe?

**Details**:
From the manpage for isatty(): isatty - test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal. http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty

Comment: Doesn't the TTY belong to the whole process group, rather than to any one process?

Comment: From the manual: it actually checks if the file descriptor number belongs to the terminal. So, stdin would normally be terminal. But when using pipes, it would not be TTY. I'm following same solution described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564503/how-do-i-check-if-my-program-has-data-piped-into-it.

Comment: Hm. Try calling `setsid()` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Including setsid() doesn't help.

Comment: try running your program as a daemon process see if it return 0 in that case. (create a cron job)

Comment: Tricky! I was running my program from eshell (emacs). Running from a bare terminal (ssh) it works fine. Why is that?

Comment: How are you running your program? Can you provide a [mcve]? The code you're providing should work assuming your process isn't running inside another process.

Comment: Is the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable pointing to a custom `isatty`? I know I've done that before...

Comment: Under my eshell LD_PRELOAD is unset.